# link in WP not going to the right page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I'm working with WP on different subdomains, and for some reason a link on the landing page isn't going to the subdomain, but rather it's trying to go to a page that doesn't exist on the main domain level. I'm guessing this is some kind of auto direct issue, but the link is correct and I'm not sure what is causing this.

The main domain is in  staging status: staging2.definingstudios.com.  There are three links there, Lifestyle, Schools, and Commercial. The linnk to schools had been doing this too, but then it stopped and is working properly, but the Lifestyle one is trying to go elsewhere.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Christine

Comment: Welcome! Please checkout, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you provide proper details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a WP issue but generally an issue with the theme. They tend to save this data in the DB. A lot of the time its serialized and doesn't get updated.

You can do a few things. Search the DB and see if you can find it. Use a plugin to do it or 95% of the time just go into that page and update/save and it generally fixes it.

Comment: perhaps when the staging goes live it will fix itself... but I'll try searching the DB and then also try a plugin and report back...

Comment: Not having any luck. Search and replace didn't work. Not sure where to look in the database.... Tried changing the theme, that didn't work.  :(

Comment: You can use something like - https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ to search for that URL and replace it. It allows a DRY run so you don't change anything when testing. 

I run into issues like this with DIVI all the time where the site was either developed somewhere else or they have changed domains and all the URLS are messed up because they are saved into the DB.

Comment: Actually, looking at the code. Just edit that page. It looks like someone tried to do that already or forgot to add http:// or https:// to the link.

href="lifestyle.definingstudios.com/"

Comment: Ive narrowed it down to the heading widget in elementor causing the issue.... Have no idea why.